# Stuck in JavaScript Adding Class

Tags: javascript

```
    for(i=0;i<document.querySelectorAll(".skill-images").length;i++){

document.querySelectorAll(".skill-images")[i].addEventListener("click", function (){

    document.querySelectorAll(".skill-images")[i].classList.add("imghover");

    setTimeout(function(){
      document.querySelectorAll(".skill-images")[i].classList.remove("imghover");
    },500);
});
```

}

Where am i going wrong? I just need to add a class imghover on a click.

My all images have a class = "skill-images:

Please someone check and solve it!

Comment: what have you done to debug ? Please note you shouldn't use 4 calls of querySelectorAll, you are asking the browser 4 times to compute the collection of items matching your selectors ; depending on your html, this can be large collections ; you'd better store the `querySelectorAll` return in a var and use that later

Comment: I have done that, still not working. Please help me. should i use querySelector() everytime.?

Answer (score 1):

You're binding a `click` event, which is triggered when user clicks on the element, not hover over it. If possible, it's better to stick to css for hover states and do it like this:

```css
.skill-images:hover {
   // Put here your rules which were defined for .imghover
}
```

Comment: what if i add mouseover instead of click?

Comment: @DevenderSharma why bothering with javascript when css does the job...

Comment: I am learning it, just got through a problem :) The point here is to add a class somehow, Please help in that

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var skillImagesElement = document.querySelectorAll(".skill-images");

    for(var i=0; i<skillImagesElement.length;i++){
        skillImagesElement[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            var eachElement = this;
            eachElement.classList.add("imghover");

            setTimeout(function(){
                eachElement.classList.remove("imghover");
            },500);
        },false);
    }
```